# Use Laravel API by another (external) Laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I would like to use the API-Routes of my first Laravel instance (I will call this *Laravel API provider*) by my second instance (I will call this *Laravel API client*).

The *Laravel API provider* is based on vue/vuex/vue-router and the API-routes are protected by `laravel/passport`.

One example for a protected route on the *Laravel API provider*:

```
/*Categories Routes*/
Route::group(['prefix' => 'categories'], function ($router) {

    /*Index*/
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/', 'CategoriesApiController@index')
        ->name('api.categories.index');
});
```

So now I created this call on my *Laravel API client*:

```
 $http= new Client();
        $response = $http->request('POST', 'https://laravel-api-provider.local/oauth/token', [
            'headers' => [
                'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id' => '2',
                'client_secret' => 'secret',
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'username' => 'test@example.org',
                'password' => 'password',
            ],
        ]);

        return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

This returns:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 31622400,
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC......",
  "refresh_token": "def5020084262c0659e6f916b4da2c33e2a78de2206d......"
}
```

Seems good.  So my next question is: How do I call protected routes (like `/api/categories/index`) using `$response` on my *Laravel API client*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passport uses bearer tokens, this is set in the `Authorization` header. The token should have `'Bearer '` in front of the token. So you could achieve it with something like this.

```
$token = $response['access_token'];

$http= new Client();
$response = $http->request('GET', 'https://laravel-api-provider.local/api/categories/index', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
    ],
]);
```

For most optimal usage, store the token and when the calls is not authorized anymore use the refresh token to get a new one. But for now this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Another way is to use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client since v7